# make animations that can operate with mouse

Tags: qt, qml

I'm having a hard time making animations.
There are some rectangles included, and I'd like to make an animation that two rectangles change their color at the same time.
But I have no idea how to do it.

I used sequential animation to make it happen. But it didn't worked.
Also, I'd like to make this animation happen in many boxes, I have no idea how to make it in order. It should be work in different time.

```cpp
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12


Window {
    id: idWindow
    visible: true
    width: 1200
    height: 800

    Rectangle{
        id: content
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "#F0F0F0"
        anchors.rightMargin: 0
        anchors.bottomMargin: 0
        anchors.leftMargin: 0
        anchors.topMargin: 0

        Column{
            id: list
            anchors.verticalCenterOffset: -78
            anchors.horizontalCenterOffset: -436
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
            spacing: 10

            Rectangle {
                id: pf0
                width: 40
                height: 40
                radius: 0
                anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                border.width: 1
                Text {
                    text: "pf-0"
                    anchors.centerIn: parent

                }
            }
// ......
        }

        Column {
            id: list1
            x: 4
            y: -3
            width: 199
            height: 241
            anchors.verticalCenterOffset: -106
            anchors.horizontalCenterOffset: -73
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            spacing: 10
            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter

            Rectangle {
                id: pa0
                width: 120
                height: 40
                radius: 0
                anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                border.width: 1

                Text {
                    text: "page-A0"
                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                    anchors.horizontalCenterOffset: 3
                    anchors.verticalCenterOffset: 0
               }

            }

 // ......
        }

        Rectangle {
            id: rectangle
            x: 794
            y: 370
            width: 200
            height: 200
            color: "#5af751"

            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: rectangle
                onPressed: playbanner.start()
            }

            SequentialAnimation {
                id: playbanner
                running: true 
                    ColorAnimation {
                        target: pa0
                        from: "white"
                        to: "black"
                        duration: 1000
                    } 

                    ColorAnimation {
                        target: pf0
                        from: "white"
                        to: "black"
                        duration: 1000
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I expect that when I click the rectangle, the color should be change. However, not worked.

And also I'd like to know, when there are more boxes, how can I make boxes change color in order.

Comment: Please have a read on [mcve]s. Basically, remove any parts of your code that are not relevant to the question.

Answer (score 1):

- First thing is if you want to make a animation where the color of the rectangles change at the same time then you should use the ParallelAnimation not SequentialAnimation.
- You need to remove the running property from the ColorAnimation or set it to false, because you need the animation to happen when you click on the rectangle, so if you set running to true then it will happen as soon as the component gets loaded.
- The reason why the animation is not running is because you have not set the property in color animation.

Check the code below:

```
ParallelAnimation {
    id: playbanner         
    ColorAnimation {
        target: pa0
        from: "white"
        to: "black"
        duration: 1000
        property: "color"
    }
    ColorAnimation {
        target: pf0
        from: "white"
        to: "black"
        duration: 1000
        property: "color"
    }
}
```